# Tabindex is not properly working in winforms

Tags: c#

I have two textboxes `txtdays` and `txtnoofPer` `TabIndex` respectively 55 and 56.
but while i entering it's not working.

i tried the `KeyDownEvent` also

```
 private void txtdays_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if(e.KeyCode==Keys.Enter)
        {
            txtnoofPer.Select();
        }
    }
```

instead of move to next tab index it focus to some other textboxes..

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do there. TabIndex means taht when you hit tabulator the fodus gets to the next control.

Comment: not on hitting tabulator but enter the focus gets to the next control.

Comment: `TextBox.Select` (on MSDN): "Selects a range of text in the text box."

Comment: No, on hitting tab. For enter you need to implement it yourself. I would recommend to use linq to get the control with the nex highest TabIndex from the windows Control collection.

Comment: Do you have your controls grouped together in a container such as a panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TabIndex: "*Gets or sets a value that determines the order in which elements receive focus when the user navigates through controls by using the TAB key.*" 
So it will go to the next textbox when you press Tab, not Enter key.

Update: If you want to use the Enter key for that operation, you can use this:

```
if(Keys.Enter == e.KeyCode)
{
   SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
   e.Handled = true;//set to false if you need that textbox gets enter key
}
```

Source: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/440784/go-to-next-tab-index-by-enter

Comment: That is not safe. The Tab could be handled elsewise (e.g. by a window stealing the focus in the wrong moment)

Comment: Additionally this is stolen from this thread http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/440784/go-to-next-tab-index-by-enter. Without credits. Shame on you.

Comment: @RomanoZumbé: I don't need credits, the help is important here, isn't it?? And further more - this is a common piece of functionality and this is not the only one source of it, but at least 100 more places. I'm not here to create a new language and kinky algorithms for simple operations!

Comment: Sorry if my comment was to rude. But it is more elegant to tell if you found something elsewhere. No offense.

Answer (score 1):

To implement this logic, for a hit on enter, try this code example:

```
private void txtdays_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if(e.KeyCode==Keys.Enter)
        {
            var control = this.Controls
                    .Cast<Control>()
                    .Where(r => r.TabIndex == txtdays.TabIndex + 1).First();
            control.Focus();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've tested this myself and it worked for me. Did you debug the code? What control is assigned to the variable control?

Comment: Additionally please make sure that the TabIndexes are as you expecting. While debugging the code above check the TabIndizes at that specific time. Perhaps they are altered somewhere else in your code. For a quick solution just execute `txtnoofPer.Focus();`

Comment: while debugging its move to txtdays textbox but while functioning it's focus to another dropdown name cbguest

Comment: Please set a breakpoint on the `control.Focus();` line and take a look at which control it is refering. Additionally look whats the TabIndex of that control.

Comment: It's solved ....i just replaced the new txtbox control its working fine .....thanks to all.....for help

Comment: If my answer was right, please mark it as the correct answer. This will help others. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use focus.

```
txtnoofPer.Focus();
```

Comment: Ya i tried this but the focus not get to txtnoofPer....instead of it focus to another textboxes.....

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
private void txtdays_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            txtnoofPer.Focus();
            txtnoofPer.Select(0, txtnoofPer.Text.Length);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by replace the textbox with new one

Answer (score 0):

If   txtdays_KeyDown  event not fired . see it using debug.

then enable Form Property called it KeyPreview. set the value true.

then you should call this function  ProcessTabKey(true);

Answer (score 0):

In design view go to View -> Tab Order

Click on the numbers on controls in the order you want to tab through them

The problem is sometimes the parent control e.g. panel has a tab index that interferes with what you are trying to achieve